# Continuity via monotonic sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

It is well known that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $p$ if for any sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to $p$, $\{f(a_n)\}$ converges to $f(p)$.
My question is whether we can restrict to monotonic sequences: Is $f$ continuous if for any monotonic sequence $\{a_n\}$ converging to $p$, $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(p)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any convergent sequence, you can always construct a monotonic subsequence.  (There has to be an infinite number of either increasing terms or decreasing terms since the sequence has infinite terms).   So yes,  you can use the monotonic version because it would also cover the non-monotonic case via the subsequence